# Is it possible to include a CSS class name in jQuery .animate()

Tags: jquery

With jQuery `.animate()`, I use to write like `.animate({ 'font-size': "24px", 'color': '#555' }, 1000 )` to animate the item as per the CSS attributes.

Is there a way in which I write a css class

```
.className{
    font-size : "24px";
    color : "#333";
}
```

and use that class to perform the `.animate()` function so that I don't have to write all the CSS attributes as the properties of the jquery `.animate()` function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "vanilla" jQuery, but jQuery UI has animation for [addClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) (plus [toggle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/), [switch](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/), and [remove](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/)).